# how i check a word if it appears on a website in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i try to search solutions, but i not succeeded, this is my try:

```
    words = ['mild', 'other', 'covid', '2019']
website = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19').read()
for word in words:
    if word in website:
        print(word)
    else:
         print(word, "not found")
```

Comment: What does not succeeding look like? Do you get an error, does it do the wrong thing, does it do nothing? You get help quicker if you don't make people guess. If you get an error, include the entire error message (including traceback) in your question.

Comment: What happened when you tried the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What happened when you tried to diagnose the problem? For example, did you check that `website` got a value that looks like what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

When running your code I get

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

That means that when using comparator `in` you need to supply string.
Change your 4th line to:

```py
if word in str(website, encoding='utf-8')):
    ....
```

Comment: It would be better to do the conversion ahead of time, rather than each time through the loop.

Comment: This is not the correct way to convert the `bytes` into a `str`. It will give `"b'whatever'"` not `"whatever"`. It will technically work here, but sets up a bad habit.

Comment: @Kemp using `encoding` corrects that, already corrected my answer

Comment: The way I've normally seen it done would be `website.decode('utf-8')`, but this works too.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
website = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19').read()
```

`website` is `bytes` as `urllib.request.urlopen` is made for fetching files, which do not have to be textes. You need to decode it before treating as text, you first need to know encoding used, which you might found in `Content-Type` header:

```
import urllib.request
resource = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19')
print(resource.getheader('Content-Type'))
```

output:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

which mean you should `.decode` your bytes using `UTF-8` like so

```
website = resource.read().decode('UTF-8')
```

which result in `website` being `str`.